# Unable to insert the special charcter into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update one string value which contains `/n` into mysql table but after update that string value creates new line.

I am using some code which is given below.

```
require_once 'include/dbconfig.php';
$tracking_id='108597711876';
$payment_mode='Debit Card';
$card_name='Maestro Debit Card';
$status_message='SUCCESS';
$bank_ref_no='327446';
$str="tracking_id : ".$tracking_id."\\npayment_mode : ".$payment_mode."\\ncard_name : ".$card_name."\\nstatus_message : ".$status_message."\\nbank_ref_no : ".$bank_ref_no;
$qry ="UPDATE cb_all_state set comment='".$str."' WHERE id=1";
$sql=mysqli_query($connect,$qry);
```

I need to entry the string value as below format directly.

```
tracking_id : 108597711876\npayment_mode : Debit Card\ncard_name : Maestro Debit Card\nstatus_message : SUCCESS\nbank_ref_no : 327446
```

But after update I am getting the following data inside the column.

```
tracking_id : 108597711876
payment_mode : Debit Card
card_name : Maestro Debit Card
status_message : SUCCESS
bank_ref_no : 327446
```

Here actually I need to entry the string value with `/n` but it creates new line after update.

Comment: Maybe `\\\\n`? Kind of clunky, but might work.

Comment: To make myself more clear. This is a classical example of SQL injection. Your `$str` is correct (you could avoid double backslash by using single quotes though), but when you execute the query you are not using prepared statements and the `\n` is interpreted by SQL parser as newline character. Use prepared statements and your nightmares with SQL should be over.

Comment: @Dharman A prepared statement will turn a new line character into a `\n`? It's still not clear to me how exactly it is a duplicate. A prepared statement just tells you what is data and what is not. If the server interprets the characters `\n` as a newline, it won't matter if the server knows what's data and what's not. What the OP seems to need is literally the characters '\' + 'n' next to each other.  That means they need an escaped backslash, like so: `\\n`, or from PHP (since they need two escaped backslashes) `\\\\n`. Maybe I'm still just misunderstanding you.

Comment: @Chipster You are correct with the fact that if you make a string like this `$str = "\\n";` then you need 2 backslashes before `n`, but if you use single quotes you only need 1 backslash `$str = '\n';` [Try it!](https://3v4l.org/USRcT) You do not need to escape the backslash again if you use prepared statements because at this point the data is pure data and it will be put into DB as literal characters `\n`. The way OP does it, there is one more parser which will turn these 2 characters into a newline, which is not what OP wants.

Comment: @Dharman I got you now. That sounds like a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

[mysqli_real_escape_string($str)](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) should assist you here as it will handle escaping special characters like new lines. In your code this should be:

```php
$str="tracking_id : ".$tracking_id."\npayment_mode : ".$payment_mode.
  "\ncard_name : ".$card_name."\nstatus_message : ".$status_message.
  "\nbank_ref_no : ".$bank_ref_no;
$qry ="UPDATE cb_all_state set comment='". mysqli_real_escape_string($str). "' WHERE id=1";
$sql=mysqli_query($connect,$qry);
```

Comment: @Dharman this has nothing to do with the topic of the question author. You can nearly always bloat questions and answers with this kind of comments. In the above example there isn't ANY user input so why would you expect to see input validation in an answer?

Comment: I am not talking about user input validation. I pointed out that you should not recommend `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: @Dharman Which is wrong, there is nothing bad about the function when used in the right context. The author's question is "...Here actually I need to entry the string value with \n but it creates new line ..." and what mysqli_real_escape_string does is escaping special characters: "Characters encoded are NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z. ".

Comment: Ok, true, but I still don't understand why would `mysqli_real_escape_string` be better here than actual prepared statements?

Comment: @Dharman because it does not require rewriting existing code on the author's side. He has an existing application, a current problem and seeks a solution to it. Why should I recommend the author to start from scratch?

Comment: Nowhere in his code is he using anything which would require a shim in the form of `mysqli_real_escape_string`. The rewriting would mean changing only one line of code which is the same effort as your suggestion.

Comment: @Dharman feel free to add an answer. It's a good idea to show some alternatives, especially if they are safer than what the author used before or other commenters like me recommend.

Comment: I gave an alternative. I voted to close as duplicate.

Comment: @Dharman Why? It's not a duplicate of that question at all! It's totally un-related to the question the OP has put forth. Good advice, but NOT a duplicate.

Comment: See my other comment.